# how to filter json object by String value in android?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have view pager with fragment in recyclerview i want to parse json data based on value pair in first fragment i want to all data if device is online and second data  based on offline value any suggestion would  be appreciated.
My Json Value.

```
[
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1475",
    "siteName": "IVIS1475    SBI-CHE-Coimbatore-Kangeyampalayam",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1354",
    "siteName": "IVIS1354    SBI-Trichy S.P Office Pudukottai",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1476",
    "siteName": "IVIS1476    SBI-Coimbatore Redfields Coimbatore",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": ""
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1355",
    "siteName": "IVIS1355    SBI-CHE-Pondicherry-Thiruvandarkoil Busstand",
    "deviceStatus": "Online",
    "hddStatus": "Not Ok",
    "powerSource": ""
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1597",
    "siteName": "IVIS1597    SBI-Chennai 1 Melvisharam Vellore",
    "deviceStatus": "Online",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Mains"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS2203",
    "siteName": "IVIS2203    SBI-Coimbatore Kutchery Strt Udamalpet",
    "deviceStatus": "Online",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS1478",
    "siteName": "IVIS1478    SBI-Coimbatore Officers Club ",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS2205",
    "siteName": "IVIS2205    SBI-Coimbatore Municipal Cmplx Udamalpet",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS2206",
    "siteName": "IVIS2206    SBI-Coimbatore Railway Station Tirupur",
    "deviceStatus": "Offline",
    "hddStatus": "Not Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
},
{
    "deviceId": "IVIS2207",
    "siteName": "IVIS2207    SBI-Coimbatore Dr Nanjappa Rd Coimbatore",
    "deviceStatus": "Online",
    "hddStatus": "Not Ok",
    "powerSource": "Battery"
}]
```

Based on device status i want to filter json data and add into recyclerivew this my recyclerveiw code.

```
RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, projectDetailUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response)
        {


               progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

               GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
               Gson mGson = builder.create();
               posts =new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(mGson.fromJson(response, ProDetail[].class)));

               adapter = new OnSiteAdapter( posts);
               recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
               final List<ProDetail> finalPosts = posts;
               ItemClickSupport.addTo(recyclerView).setOnItemClickListener(
                       new ItemClickSupport.OnItemClickListener()
                       {
                           @Override
                           public void onItemClicked(RecyclerView recyclerView, int position, View v) {
                               // do it
                               String deviceId = finalPosts.get(position).getDeviceId();
                               Intent proDetailIntent = new Intent(getContext(), SensorDetailAcitivity.class);
                               proDetailIntent.putExtra("deviceid", deviceId);
                               startActivity(proDetailIntent);


                           }
                       }
               );

           }



    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
        {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: Can you use java 8 and lamda?

Comment: andorid studio not supported java 8

Comment: It does, take a look at https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create two separate lists and update `RecyclerView` with them

Java 8:

```
List<PostDetail> onlinePostDetail = posts.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getDeviceStatus().equals("Online"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
List<PostDetail> offlinePostDetail = posts.stream()
    .filter(p -> p.getDeviceStatus().equals("Offline"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

below Java 8:

```
 List<PostDetail> onlinePostDetail = new ArrayList();
 List<PostDetail> offlinePostDetail = new ArrayList();
 for(PostDetail p: posts) {
     if(p.getDeviceStatus().equals("Online")) {
         onlinePostDetail.add(p);
     } else if(p.getDeviceStatus().equals("Offline")) {
         offlinePostDetail.add(p);
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create two list based on posts list

```
List<PostDetail> onlineList = new ArrayList<>();
List<PostDetail> offlineList = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < posts.size(); i++) {
    if(posts.get(i).getDeviceStatus.equals("Online")){
        onlineList.add(posts.get(i));
    } else if(posts.get(i).getDeviceStatus.equals("Offline")) {
        offlineList.add(posts.get(i));
    }
}
```

Then you can show these 2 lists in different screens or where ever you need

Answer (score 1):

i use retrofit in android studio bumblebee 2022 and in response use this

```
 override fun onResponse(call: Call<Responseagro>, response: Response<Responseagro>) {

          
            val result : List<agrolokasiitem?>? = response.body()!!.data

            val resultsearch = result!!.filter{agrolokasiitem: 
            agrolokasiitem? -> agrolokasiitem?.'WHAT YOUR OBJECT'.equals("YOUR SEARCH") }
            val layoutManager1 =
             LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
       
            recycleview.layoutManager = layoutManager1
            val sadapter = Adapter(applicationContext, resultsearch)
            recycleview.adapter = sadapter
            androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            recycleview .setHasFixedSize(true)

        }
```